# R - how to get a multi-level list using list.files

Tags: r, list, directory-structure

I have a folder structure like this:

```
- ConditionA
     - Subcondition1
          - data1.Rds
          - data2.Rds
     - Subcondition2
          - data1.Rds
          - data2.Rds
- ConditionB
     - Subcondition1
          - data1.Rds
          - data2.Rds
     - Subcondition2
          - data1.Rds
          - data2.Rds
```

Using the `list.files(recursive = T, full.names = T)` gives the following:

```
"./ConditionA/Subcondition1/data1.Rds"
"./ConditionA/Subcondition1/data2.Rds"
"./ConditionA/Subcondition2/data1.Rds"
"./ConditionA/Subcondition2/data2.Rds"
"./ConditionB/Subcondition1/data1.Rds"
"./ConditionB/Subcondition1/data2.Rds"
"./ConditionB/Subcondition2/data1.Rds"
"./ConditionB/Subcondition2/data2.Rds"
```

However, what I want instead is a list of lists representing the nested folder structure. The list should be identical to this one I will construct manually here:

```
sublist1 <- list("data1.Rds", "data2.Rds")
sublist2 <- list("data1.Rds", "data2.Rds")
sublist3 <- list("data1.Rds", "data2.Rds")
sublist4 <- list("data1.Rds", "data2.Rds")

sublist5 <- list(sublist1, sublist2)
names(sublist5) <- c("Condition1", "Condition2")

sublist6 <- list(sublist3, sublist4)
names(sublist6) <- c("Condition1", "Condition2")

final_list <- list(sublist5, sublist6)
names(final_list) <- c("ConditionA", "ConditionB")
```

Let's see:

```
final_list
```

Gives the output:

```
$ConditionA
$ConditionA$Condition1
$ConditionA$Condition1[[1]]
[1] "data1.Rds"

$ConditionA$Condition1[[2]]
[1] "data2.Rds"


$ConditionA$Condition2
$ConditionA$Condition2[[1]]
[1] "data1.Rds"

$ConditionA$Condition2[[2]]
[1] "data2.Rds"



$ConditionB
$ConditionB$Condition1
$ConditionB$Condition1[[1]]
[1] "data1.Rds"

$ConditionB$Condition1[[2]]
[1] "data2.Rds"


$ConditionB$Condition2
$ConditionB$Condition2[[1]]
[1] "data1.Rds"

$ConditionB$Condition2[[2]]
[1] "data2.Rds"
```

How can I achieve this to be automated instead of constructing the list manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fun exercise is to do this with a recursive function.

```r
fun <- function(L) {
  len1 <- lengths(L) == 1
  c(
    L[len1],
    if (any(!len1)) lapply(
      split(lapply(L[!len1], `[`, -1), sapply(L[!len1], `[[`, 1)),
      fun)
  )
}
```

Using a similar tree hierarchy:

```r
list.files(recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
# [1] "./ConditionA/Subcondition1/data1.Rds" "./ConditionA/Subcondition1/data2.Rds" "./ConditionA/Subcondition2/data1.Rds"
# [4] "./ConditionA/Subcondition2/data2.Rds" "./ConditionB/Subcondition1/data1.Rds" "./ConditionB/Subcondition1/data2.Rds"
# [7] "./ConditionB/Subcondition2/data1.Rds" "./ConditionB/Subcondition2/data2.Rds"
```

We can do this:

```r
list.files(recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) |>
  sub("^\\./", "", x = _) |>
  # optional? just stripping the leading "./"
  strsplit("/") |>
  fun() |>
  str()
# List of 2
#  $ ConditionA:List of 2
#   ..$ Subcondition1:List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr "data1.Rds"
#   .. ..$ : chr "data2.Rds"
#   ..$ Subcondition2:List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr "data1.Rds"
#   .. ..$ : chr "data2.Rds"
#  $ ConditionB:List of 2
#   ..$ Subcondition1:List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr "data1.Rds"
#   .. ..$ : chr "data2.Rds"
#   ..$ Subcondition2:List of 2
#   .. ..$ : chr "data1.Rds"
#   .. ..$ : chr "data2.Rds"
```

(The same output, but compactified with `str()` for presentation here.)

Comment: (I actually believe I did something like this many years ago in undergrad ... in the Scheme language, not R. :-)